# Windows Environment Setup for Windows MAUI Desktop Application Development with Jetbrains Rider

Tags: .net, windows, desktop-application, rider, maui

I'm wondering if I can get help from the community here to provide the documentation Windows Environment Setup for Windows MAUI Desktop Application Development with Jetbrains Rider. Also Microsoft Visual Studio IDE is no needed.

I saw Jetbrains team prepared well [the documentation of MAUI for macOS environment](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2022/05/25/macos-environment-setup-for-maui-development/) setup but they don't provide Windows one yet.

Comment: Hi.  As written, your question is off-topic.  Please review [*What topics can I ask about here?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  That said, the blog post you pointed at was written with macOS in mind, but the steps should be very similar on Windows.  Give it a try and if you get stuck then you will have a specific question to ask here. Good luck!

Comment: Hello, I am just visiting right now. Let me review this what values that make it out off topic. Furthermore, the Jetbrains team actually don't support Windows setup even you assume there is similiarity to macOS. It does not work due to unsupported